# Variable centering on the sampling distribution of the coefficient estimates

Tags: r, simulation, bernoulli-distribution, centering

I think the question may be silly but I'm trying to learn statistics and R and this is really hard for me because I'm a newbie of both. 
I have this exercise to do.

> Carry out a simulation experiment to study the effect of variable centering
>   on the sampling distribution of the coefficient estimates. The setting is as
>   follows: Yi ∼ Ber(pi); i = 1,..,n, where logit(pi) = β0 + β1Gi + β2xi, where
>   n = 50; Gi = 1 for i = 1,...,20 and Gi = 0 for i = 21,...,50; and xi = i=n.
>   Repeat the following N = 300 times: (i) generate values for the Bernoulli
>   variables; (ii) compute the MLEs of the regression coefficients with the glmfunction; (iii) store the coefficients into an N × 3 matrix. Switching from the
>   original x-values to the centered ones will not change β^2 but the intercept
>   changes to β^0 + β^2 × 25.5/n. Use β0 = −0:9; β1 = 0:3; β2 = 1 as true values
>   in simulation. As an answer to this assignment, give the R code you used;
>   give scatter plots of (β^0; β^2) in both cases. What practical implication does
>   the result have in applications?

This is what I did (*what I've tried to do*):

```
N<-50
i<-c(1:50)
x<-i/N
```

I generate x as the exercise wants

```
G<-c(rep(1,round(N/2.5)),rep(0,N-round(N/2.5)))
```

Here I just repeat "1" for i=1,...20 and "0" for i=21,...,50

```
X<-cbind(rep(1,N),G,x)
```

I just bind G and x. 
Now the problems starts:

```
B<-c(log(0.4/0.6),0.3,1)
```

I have a previous example from my lectures and I've tried to follow it, but this is the step I don't understand. I have troubles about both the statistic behind and the coding.

I create B, in which I put my logit(p), equal to my log(p/(1-p)), so in my case log(0.4/0.6). Then in class we bind two other numbers which should be the beta parameters. But I don't know which parameter I should put here. The exercise says:

> Use β0 = −0,9; β1 = 0,3; β2 = 1

But in class we just added two of them and I don't remember which ones. I put β1 = 0,3 and β2 = 1 just to continue the exercise.

Then we did:

```
lp<-X%*%B
p<-exp(lp)/(1+exp(lp))
```

This is where I obtain my logit model. 
lp is my logit^(-1) and p is the probability i.

Then in class we did:

```
N0<-100
B0<-matrix(rep(0,N0*3),ncol=3)
for (i in 1:N0){
  U<-runif(N)
  Y<-as.numeric(U<=p)
  lreg<-glm(Y~G+x,family=binomial)
  B0[i,]<-coef(lreg)
}

summary(B0)
hist(B0[,1])
hist(B0[,2])
hist(B0[,3])
plot(B0[,1],B0[,2])
plot(B0[,1],B0[,3])
plot(B0[,2],B0[,3])
```

Which is where I compute the MLEs of the regression coefficients with the glm function repeating for 300 times and I store the coefficients into an N × 3 matrix. Then I have to analyze the histograms and plot the relations between B0[,1],B0[,2] and B0[,3]. Fine.

But then in the exercise there is:

> Switching from the
>   original x-values to the centered ones will not change β^2 but the intercept
>   changes to β^0 + β^2 × 25.5/n

Why there is a 25.5 out of nowhere there?

I have a total mess in my mind. I don't even understand what centering even means in this exercise. It's so hard when I'm not taught anything and they expect me to just understand out of nowhere. I can't find anything useful on the net.
Can somebody help me? I really tried to solve it by myself. 
Thanks a lot if you can help me.

Comment: I cannot help much, but at least I see one mistake in your B. Given the data you provided it is:
B<-c(-0.9,0.3,1)